# AndroidTestCase class file version mismatch

Tags: android

I am looking at AndroidTestCase class in android 2.2 source code, it
has a method getTestContext. when i tried to access the same function
using android.jar packaged in sdk i don't see this methods.

Not only this i see several methods which are public are not seen when
i use android-sdk-for-windows/platforms/android-8/android.jar packaged
with the sdk. In my project i have set my android api level to 8.

when i try to right click and look at the class version they are
pointing to 1.5 , i would expect they point to 2.2.

do i need to compile everything manually to get all public methods in
2.2 source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because actually they hid the method using a comment annotation:

```
/**
 * @hide
 */
public Context getTestContext() {
    return mTestContext;
}
```

You will see a lot of those @hide in Android; some people say that they are hidden features that are still in test phase. Take a look at this article for more information: [Why some classes/methods aren’t presented in SDK and DroidDoc](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/?p=132).

Comment: Surprisingly all these api's are used by phone verndors to develop applications, so will they be maintaining sdk version by themselves?